# ng-repeat bind collection filtered by a boolean using tabs, when I update the collection the filter doesn't re-apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that displays a collection filtered by a boolean using tabs (favourite item), when I update the collection the filter doesn't re-apply. I have:

all items | favourites

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

When it first load (using json) the collection from the server, the tabs work fine and filters the collection. When you click in an item, I update the favourite property of the item, but the filter doesn't updates and if you click in the tabs it seems that the data doesn't get updated.

Code:

HTML:

```
<button class="btn" ng-model="section" value="all-items" ng-click="filterCriteria={};   activate('all-items')" ng-class="{disabled: products.length == 0, active: section == 'all-items'}">All items ({{products.length}})</button>

<button class="btn" ng-model="section" value="favourites" ng-click="activate('favourites'); filterCriteria.Favourite = true;" ng-class="{disabled: (products | filter: {Favourite:true}).length < 0, active: section == 'favourites'}">Favourites</button>

<!-- List of products -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products | filter: filterCriteria">
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="favouriteClick(product)">Favourite</button>
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('ProductListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http, $filter)     {

    $http.get('/Products').success(function (data) {
        $scope.products = data;
    });

    $scope.filterCriteria = {};
    $scope.section = "all-items";

    $scope.activate = function (option) {
        $scope.section = option;
    };

    $scope.favouriteClick = function (product) {

        product.favourite = !product.favourite;

        // Sync with back-end
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/SetFavourite',
            data: 'name=' + product.Sku + '&value=' + product.favourite,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });
    };
} ]);
```

Any feedback greatly appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT**

I have created a fiddle with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/njrHm/

Comment: What does `$scope.products` look like after it loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a casing issue.  You've got:

```
ng-click="activate('favourites'); filterCriteria.Favourite = true;"
```

...and then you've got:

```
product.favourite = !product.favourite;
```

I gather you want to change your `ngClick` to use lowercase `favourite`.